# run time map configuration

Tags: configuration, mapreduce, runtime, hadoop-streaming

I want to know if there is a way to know the MAP and Reduce Configuration in Apache Hadoop at run time ?
I tried to look up a lot on various forums but was unable to get it . Everywhere there are loads of codes but not exactly the answer to this .
Please help me . Thanks in advance for your valuable time .

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? what do you mean "know the MAP and Reduce Configuration"?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to know the number of mappers and reducers assigned to my job ,,after the execution has started .

Comment: "know" = "see the number"? or "know" = "get this number in a program and use it"?. The number of reducers is set by you, so you know it at all times. For the number of mappers, you can either see it in the Web UI, or get it from the job configuration.

Comment: get the number in a program ans use it as input to any other function in my program